# List Subscriptions for Azure Active Directory User

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to get the Azure Subscriptions to which a Azure AD user is linked to.

I tried using the Microsoft Graph Api, but was not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

A `GET` call to `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2014-04-01` should give you a list of subscription for user that got issue the token. You should be using Azure API not Graph.